# `[data getBytes:&buff length:sizeof(buff)]` got wrong bytes

Tags: ios, objective-c

In iOS 16+, when the `NSData *data` ranges between 0 and 255, the `int16_t buff` retrieves values not within the range of 0 to 255, but rather 29440 to 29696.

```objectivec
- (void)system:(id)system features:(void (^)(NSArray*))features
{
    [self read:TAPropertyTypeAvailableFeatures system:system handler:^(NSDictionary* data, NSError* error){
        
        NSArray* datas = [data objectForKey:@"value"];
        NSMutableArray* numbers = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        
        for(NSData* data in datas)
        {
            int16_t buff;
            [data getBytes:&buff length:sizeof(buff)];
            NSNumber* number = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:buff];
            [numbers addObject:number];
        }
        
        features(numbers);
    }];
}
```

When I upgraded my MacBook to 14.1.2 and Xcode to 15.0.1, I encountered an issue with this function that I rebuilt.

In iOS 16+, when the `NSData *data` ranges between 0 and 255, the `int16_t buff` retrieves values not within the range of 0 to 255, but rather 29440 to 29696.

However, in iOS 15, it still remains between 0 and 255.

This problem never occurred before. Changing int16_t to int resolves the issue.

What is causing this issue?
Is it possible to continue using `int16_t` without encountering this problem?

Comment: Without knowing how the value was encoded into `NSData` to begin with, it's hard to know what the best solution is. But if `int` works, why try to use `int16_t`? If all you're doing is wrapping the result in `NSNumber`, then use whatever works.

Comment: Haha, when I rebuilt with `int`, it fails now.

Comment: Try `int16_t *buff = (int16_t*)data.bytes`

Comment: I just realized this could be a byte ordering issue. If you expect a 16-bit (2-byte) value to only have values in the range 0-255 then that means one byte will always be zero and the other will be 0-255. If you are getting 29440 then that's the bytes 0 and 114 in the wrong order. 29696 is 0 and 115 in the wrong order.